# Unable to cast object of type 'Linq.LookupList`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010

I get this error @ List)itemPage.userId

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.LookupList`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'

Code:

```
 List<MySitePage> userId = PagesFacade.GetPages(web.Url, (List<int?>)itemPage.userId);
```

Where userId in ItemPage is private `Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.LookupList<System.Nullable<int>> _userId ;`

```
public static List<MySitePage> GetPages(string relativeWebUrl, List<int?> userIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

`LookupList<T>` implements `IList<T>`, not List. Here's the exact implementation:

```
public sealed class LookupList<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICloneable
```

That being the case, since it's IEnumerable, you can try calling `ToList` on the collection and hope that it implements it (although I haven't actually used the Sharepoint collections). So try this instead:

```
List<MySitePage> userId = PagesFacade.GetPages(web.Url, itemPage.userId.ToList());
```